# How to use efficently in Jquery Chosen Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have used the jQuery chosen plugin. but my datasets are too large, so the select box is hanging and slow. Here is how I have implemented the plugin:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "ajaxRequest.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {fn: 'getCompanyEvent', company_id: selected_cid},
    success: function(reqResult){
        var append_string = '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">'+
                '<div class="row form-group">'+
                    '<label class="control-label col-lg-3">Select'+ ' Event</label><span class="col-lg-1">:</span>'+
                    '<div class="col-lg-8">'+ 
                        '<select class="chosen" style="width:200px;" onChange="getTemp(this)>'+
                          '<option>Select</option>';
                        $.each(reqResult.result, function(ind, va){
                            append_string += '<option value='+va.event_id+'>'+va.event_name+'</option>';
                        });    
    append_string += '</select>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+ 
            '</div>';
        $('#dynmic_slct').append(append_string);
        jQuery(".chosen").chosen();
    }
});
```

I have used to jquery `ajax()`.. ajax response result more than 20k record so it was very slow to select in UI, I want to list out more than 5k values in the select element.

Comment: i think i need some precisions about the problem: is the ajax request made at start when building the page or on each selection? (can the ajax delay be a cause of the slowdown?). What exactly is slow, the opening of the select, the scroll, the selection itself? is the plugin made for so many rows?

Comment: it's not efficient to load 5k values into a select box, regardless of the method used this will always be slower than expected. I'd rethink the way I request my data. splitting into multiple categories or paging might make things a little bit faster. or even using something other than a select box, maybe a search box or even using a database.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending `<option>` elements for all records retrieved from your backend resource. As you said your dataset is very large so it is normal for select box to hang.

What you can try is to implement a paging mechanism for your select box. For example you can parametrize your backend resource (ajaxRequest.php) with an offset like value (ajaxRequest.php?offsett=50) and then for each request you get a constant amount of elements from your data set. For example you can obtain your records by 50 items per request.

And then for each request you append your `<option>` elements as you do before. One final thing is to implement a button or something to request the next dataset elements.

Another thing that you can try is to filter the dataset by sending a parameter to the backend resource and then you can append only the filtered results to your select box. You can achieve this by implementing onChange event of jQuery Chosen Plugin Filter Text Box.